# Copyright policy of conference and sharing of article in public archive

Tags: publications, conference, copyright, self-promotion

I have few articles published in IEEE conference as well in IEEE Sponsored conference proceedings. I want to share my work on public library such as arxiv. The IEEE copy right policy states that 
 "The policy reaffirms the principle that authors are free to post their own version of their IEEE periodical or conference articles on their personal Web sites, those of their employers, or their funding agencies for the purpose of meeting public availability requirements prescribed by their funding agencies. Authors may post their version of an article as accepted for publication in an IEEE periodical or conference proceedings. Posting of the final PDF, as published by IEEE Xplore®, continues to be prohibited, except for open-access journal articles supported by payment of an article processing charge (APC), whose authors may freely post the final version". 
I have three questions:
1-The same IEEE policy is applicable to IEEE sponsored conferences or they have their own copy right policy? 
2-Few conference papers were accepted in first round of review and published as I have submitted without any modification. In such case what is my version and what is the publisher version?
3-What if a conference discontinued and their webpage is no longer available only the proceedings are available on IEEE Xplore®. What kind of copy right policy is applicable to such conference?

Comment: Answer to number 2) The publisher version is the one with all modifications from peer review and the official journal layout. The authors version (postprint) is the one with all modifications from peer review but without the journal layout, i.e. for Latex you recompile with another class or style file and for Word you remove all the formats and add your own.